# random pattern for geom_dotplot color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to show a sampling distribution of treatment effects when the null hypothesis is true, and I'd like to have the dot color randomly distributed. Right now the color groups are stacked. I'm not sure if it will look good with these 10 colors from viridis, but I'm curious to see if there is a way to make the dot colors look like we dumped out a jar full of jelly beans.

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
library(infer)

set.seed(1)

rnorm2 <- function(n,mean,sd) { mean+sd*scale(rnorm(n)) }

hap <- data.frame(trt = c(rep(0, 248), rep(1, 245)),
                  bdi3 = c(rnorm2(248, 27.52, 13.26),
                           rnorm2(245, 19.99, 15.70))
                  )
)

hap %>%
  specify(bdi3 ~ trt) %>%
  hypothesize(null = "independence") %>% 
  generate(reps = 10000, type = "permute") %>% 
  calculate(stat = "slope") %>%
  mutate(color=factor(sample(1:10, 10000, replace=TRUE))) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x=stat, fill=color)) +
  scale_color_viridis_d() +
  geom_dotplot(method = 'dotdensity', binwidth = .04,
               color="white", alpha=1,
               binpositions="all", stackgroups=TRUE,
               stackdir = "up") +
  scale_y_continuous(NULL, breaks = NULL) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Comment: The the vote to close for lack of clarity about the goal: Currently the fill follows a pattern (see the bands of color). I want these 10,000 dots to be filled with 10 colors randomly so there is no pattern to the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from [@ed_hagen on Twitter](https://twitter.com/ed_hagen/status/1244664495051399168?s=20):

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
library(infer)

set.seed(1)

rnorm2 <- function(n,mean,sd) { mean+sd*scale(rnorm(n)) }

hap <- data.frame(trt = factor(c(rep(0, 248), rep(1, 245))),
                  bdi3 = c(rnorm2(248, 27.52, 13.26),
                           rnorm2(245, 19.99, 15.70))
                  )

hap %>%
  specify(bdi3 ~ trt) %>%
  hypothesize(null = "independence") %>% 
  generate(reps = 10000, type = "permute") %>% 
  calculate(stat = "diff in means", 
            order = c("0", "1")) %>%
  mutate(color=factor(sample(1:2, 10000, replace=TRUE)),
         group=1:10000) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x=stat, fill=color, group=group)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#1f9ac9", "grey")) +
  geom_dotplot(method = 'dotdensity', binwidth = .035,
               color="white", alpha=1,
               binpositions="all", stackgroups=TRUE,
               stackdir = "up") +
  scale_y_continuous(NULL, breaks = NULL) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```